# numpy.savetxt saving every element on new line?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
with file("features.txt", "w") as outfile:
    # temp_array is an array of shape (500L,)
    np.savetxt(outfile, X=np.array(temp_array, dtype='uint8'), delimiter=",")
```

I use the above syntax to store around 10,000 arrays in a text file but I notice that all the elements are being stored on a different line.

If I load the text file using `numpy.loadtxt`, I will get an array instead of a matrix.

I know  can use `numpy.reshape` on the loaded array to convert it into a matrix but in my application the number of rows won't be known to the user who loads it.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

If you give `np.savetxt` a 1-d array, it will treat said array as a column and write each entry on a new line. I can think of two ways around this. The first is to add a new axis to your array to make it a row vector:

```
x = np.arange(5)
np.savetxt('test.txt', x[np.newaxis], fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

The second approach is to tell `np.savetxt` to use a different character other than `\n` for a newline. For example, a space:

```
np.savetxt('test.txt', x, fmt='%d', newline=' ', delimiter=',')
```

Both of these result in a file that looks like

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code for `savetxt`.  It isn't complex.  And since you are opening the file yourself, the key part of `savetxt` is:

```
for row in X:
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

In other words, it is taking your array, tweaking its shape a bit - if needed - and then writing it 'row' by 'row', line by line.

`fmt` is your input parameter replicated by the number of columns:

```
fmt = [fmt, ] * ncol
```

Try replicating that writing yourself, if you aren't happy with what `savetxt` does for you.

If `temp_array` is already an array, what is:

```
X=np.array(temp_array, dtype='uint8')
```

supposed to be doing for you?  Why the `X=` part.

Also you do you use that clip to write many arrays to a file?  I can understand repeatedly opening a file in append mode, or performing multiple `savetxt` with one open file.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I found was to make a 2D array enclosing the data:

```
np.savetxt(output_file, [[ts, serial, self.__class__.__name__, data]], '%s', delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a list, let's say in `x`. So this worked for me if I want to store the whole list in one row but each element in different column:

```
with open(file, 'a') as record_append:
    np.savetxt(record_append, [x], delimiter=',', newline='\n', fmt='%6f')
```